# How to stop XUnit Theory on the first fail?

Tags: c#, xunit

I use `Theory` with `MemberData` like this:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestParams))]
public void FijewoShortcutTest(MapMode mapMode)
{
  ...
```

and when it works, it is all fine, but when it fails XUnit iterates over all data I pass as parameters. In my case it is fruitless attempt, I would like to stop short -- i.e. when the first set of parameters make the test to fail, stop the rest (because they will fail as well -- again, it is my case, not general rule).

So how to tell XUnit to stop Theory on the first fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of a `Theory` is to have multiple *independent* tests running the same code of different data. If you only actually want *one* test, just use a `Fact` and iterate over the data you want to test within the method:

```cs
[Fact]
public void FijewoShortcutTest()
{
    foreach (MapMode mapMode in TestParams)
    {
        // Test code here
    }
}
```

That will mean you can't easily run just the test for just one `MapMode` though. Unless it takes a really long time to execute the tests for some reason, I'd just live with "if something is badly messed up, I get a lot of broken tests".